# Why is a single-producer single-consumer circular queue thread safe without locking?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, thread-safety

It seems true, but my thought has been muddy. 
can someone give a clear explanation and some crucial cases in which it always works without locking? thanks!

Comment: What is the source or context of this claim? Sure you can implement that with a single semaphore, is that what you are refering to? The semaphore also has a lock inside or it is atomic in hardware.

Comment: I would be surprised if the claim were generally true, if only because of memory model issues. What makes changes done by the producer visible to the consumer, and vice-versa? It may be possible to write a safe non-locking implementation with some use of volatile and/or atomic operations, but that can be done for many data structures.

Comment: I think this is generally true regardless the context, as long as the circular queue has a reasonably sane implementation. no lock will ever needed for using with a single consumer, single producer. The question is how all conflict cases are handled correctly.

Comment: Can you point to an implementation you have in mind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This surely depends on the implementation of the cyclic queue. However, if it is as I imagine it you have two indices - the `head` and the `tail` of the queue. The producer works with the `tail` and the consumer works with the `head`. They share the message array, but use two different pointers.

The only case in which the producer and the consumer might run into conflict is the one in which e.g. the consumer checks for new message and it arrives just after the check. However in such case the consumer will wait a bit and check once more. The correctness of the program will not be lost.

The reason why it works ok with single producer single consumer is mainly because the two users do not share much of memory. In case of multiple producers e.g. you will have more than a single thread accessing the `head` and conflicts might arraise.

**EDIT** as dasblinkenlight mentions in his comment my reasoning holds true only if both threads increment/ decrement their respective counters as last operation of their consuming/producing.

Comment: +1 You should mention that the thread safety is conditioned upon the producer writing the item into the queue first, and only then incrementing the `tail` index. In single-threaded environments the order would not matter, but in concurrent environments switching the order would break things.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks, reasonable comment.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight along the same line, should the consumer also be done with the item first, then incrementing the __head__ index?

Comment: @arrows just read it entirely and make sure it already has all needed data. Otherwise you risk loosing some of this data if the queue fills up.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight "In single-threaded environments the order would not matter" this does not hold true if environment employs preemtive scheduling.

Answer (score 6):

The real trick behind the single producer - single consumer circular queue is that the head and tail pointers are modified **atomically**. This means that if a position in memory is changed from value A to value B, an observer (i.e. reader) that reads the memory while its value is changed will get either A or B as a result, nothing else.

So your queue will not work if, for example, you are using 16-bit pointers but you are changing them in two 8-bit steps (this may happen depending on your CPU architecture and memory alignment requirements). The reader in this case may read an entirely wrong transient value.

So make sure that your pointers are modified atomically in your platform!